# Why does sklearn tf-idf vectorizer give the highest scores to stopwords?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I implemented Tf-idf with sklearn for each category of the Brown corpus in nltk library. There are 15 categories and for each of them the highest score is assigned to a stopword.

The default parameter is `use_idf=True`, so I'm using idf. The corpus is big enough to calculate right scores. So, I don't get it - why are stopwords assigned high values?

```
import nltk, sklearn, numpy
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import brown, stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

nltk.download('brown')
nltk.download('stopwords')

corpus = []
for c in brown.categories():
  doc = ' '.join(brown.words(categories=c))
  corpus.append(doc)

thisvectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = thisvectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
tfidf_matrix = X.toarray()
features = thisvectorizer.get_feature_names_out()

for array in tfidf_matrix:
  tfidf_per_doc = list(zip(features, array))
  tfidf_per_doc.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
  print(tfidf_per_doc[:3])
```

The result is:

```
[('the', 0.6893251240111703), ('and', 0.31175508121108203), ('he', 0.24393467757919754)]
[('the', 0.6907757197452503), ('of', 0.4103688069243256), ('and', 0.28727742797362427)]
[('the', 0.7263025975051108), ('of', 0.3656242079748301), ('to', 0.291070574384772)]
[('the', 0.6754696081456901), ('and', 0.31548027033056486), ('to', 0.2688347676067454)]
[('the', 0.6814989142114783), ('of', 0.45275950370682505), ('and', 0.2884682701141856)]
[('the', 0.695577697455948), ('of', 0.35341130124782577), ('and', 0.31967658612871513)]
[('the', 0.6319718467602307), ('and', 0.3252073024670836), ('of', 0.31905971640910474)]
[('the', 0.7201346766200954), ('of', 0.4283480504712354), ('and', 0.2462470090388333)]
[('the', 0.7145625245362096), ('of', 0.3795569321959571), ('and', 0.2911711705971684)]
[('the', 0.6452744438258314), ('to', 0.2965331457609836), ('and', 0.29378534827130653)]
[('the', 0.7507413874270662), ('of', 0.3364825248186412), ('and', 0.25753131787795447)]
[('the', 0.6883038024694869), ('of', 0.41770049303087814), ('and', 0.2675503490244296)]
[('the', 0.6952456562438267), ('of', 0.39285038765440655), ('and', 0.34045082029960866)]
[('the', 0.5816391566950566), ('and', 0.3731049841274644), ('to', 0.2960718382909285)]
[('the', 0.6514884130485116), ('of', 0.29645876610367955), ('to', 0.2766347756651356)]
```

Every word is a stopword. Approximately first 15 words for each category are stopwords.

If I use the parameter `stop_words` with nltk built-in stopwords, the values are more or less fine. But this doesn't make sense to me - Tf-idf should downgrade them by default, shouldn't it? Did I make a stupid mistake somewhere?

```
my_stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
thisvectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=my_stop_words)
```

```
[('said', 0.27925480211869536), ('would', 0.18907877226786665), ('man', 0.18520023334955144)]
[('one', 0.2904582969159082), ('would', 0.1989714323107254), ('new', 0.1394799739062623)]
[('would', 0.2225121466087311), ('one', 0.21533433542780428), ('new', 0.1603044497073654)]
[('would', 0.3015860042740072), ('said', 0.20105733618267146), ('one', 0.19691182409643082)]
[('state', 0.20994145654158766), ('year', 0.16516637619246616), ('fiscal', 0.1627693480477495)]
[('one', 0.27315617167196987), ('new', 0.1339515841852929), ('time', 0.12957408143413954)]
[('said', 0.25253824925464713), ('barco', 0.2297681382507305), ('one', 0.22671047376269457)]
[('af', 0.53260466412674), ('one', 0.2029977500545255), ('may', 0.12401317094240104)]
[('one', 0.29617565661385375), ('time', 0.15556701155475144), ('would', 0.14135656338388475)]
[('said', 0.22644107030344426), ('would', 0.2097909916046616), ('one', 0.1986909391388065)]
[('said', 0.2724277852935244), ('mrs', 0.19471476451838934), ('would', 0.1650670817295739)]
[('god', 0.2540052570261857), ('one', 0.18304020379411245), ('church', 0.17784155752544287)]
[('one', 0.2402151822472666), ('mr', 0.1854602509997279), ('new', 0.16073221753309752)]
[('said', 0.32053197885047946), ('would', 0.23918851593978377), ('could', 0.18980141345828996)]
[('helva', 0.34147320176374735), ('ekstrohm', 0.27116989551827), ('would', 0.2609130084842849)]
```

Comment: What happens if you use `my_stop_words = list(stopwords.words('english'))`

Answer (score 3):

Stopwords are assigned a large value as there is a problem with your corpus and tfidf calculation.

The shape of the matrix `X` is `(15, 42396)` meaning that you have only 15 documents and these documents contains 42396 different words.

The mistake is that you are concatenating all words of a given category into one document instead of using all defined document in this snippet:

```
for c in brown.categories():
  doc = ' '.join(brown.words(categories=c))
  corpus.append(doc)
```

You can modify your code to:

```
for c in brown.categories():
    doc = [" ".join(x) for x in brown.sents(categories=c)]
    corpus.extend(doc)
```

which will create one entry per document. Therefore your `X` matrix will then have a shape of `(57340, 42396)`.

This is really important as the stopwords will appear in most documents which will assign them a really low TFIDF value.

You can have a look at the 25 most important words with the following snippet:

```
import numpy as np
feature_names = thisvectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
sorted_nzs = np.argsort(X.data)[:-(25):-1]
feature_names[X.indices[sorted_nzs]]
```

Output:

```
 array(['customer', 'asked', 'properties', 'itch', 'locked', 'achieving',
        'jack', 'guess', 'criticality', 'me', 'sir', 'beckworth', 'visa',
        'will', 'casey', 'athletics', 'norms', 'yeah', 'eh', 'oh', 'af',
        'currency', 'example', 'movies'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you! Hmm, but initially with 15 documents, stopwords (like "the") definitely were in each of those 15 documents - why did they have high values then?

Comment: I actually had only 15 documents in the corpus on purpose - I want to compare the most important words for each category from the Brown corpus.

Comment: The shape of the matrix is (2351, 36092), but, I am still having this issue. The highest scores are assigned to the stop words.

Answer (score 2):

"*The corpus is big enough...*". Actually, in this case, it is the size of each document/text in the corpus that is big enough. The corpus's size is, however, only 15 documents (thus, *`N`* in `idf` would be 15). If you print `brown.categories()`, you'll see that the Brown corpus contains 15 categories, which are used as your documents. Having a small corpus means that some terms (such s stop words) will have the same distribution across documents in the corpus, and thus, will get penalised the same way by `idf`. If, for example, the word "customer" occurs just as "and" in a corpus (i.e., both appear in the same number of documents), their idf value will be the same; however, stop words (such as "and" above), due to their usually larger term frequency `tf`, they will be given higher tf-idf scores than words such as "customer"; which might appear in every document as well (as an example), but with lower term frequency.

However, the number of documents in a corpus is only part of the problem here, as, indeed, Tf-idf is known to downgrade such frequently occuring terms, while highlighting the ones that are **frequent in a document and rare in all other ones**. The second probable cause here is how sklearn's [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) (and hence, [TfidfTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html)) computes the tf-idf scores. As per the documentation, the tf-idf formula, by default, is computed as `idf(t) = log [ (1 + n) / (1 + df(t)) ] + 1` (with also cosine normalisation), which differs from the standard formula, i.e., `idf(t) = log [ n / df(t) ]`. So, in a nutshell, one should use enough sample of documents when using tf-idf. Additionally, it might be worth experimenting with the standard formula for calculating tf-idf, and see how that works for them. I recently posted an extended answer explaining this on a very similar question, showing that as the size of the corpus (i.e., number of documents) increases, more stop words (or commonly occuring words in a corpus) are eliminated. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733642/17865804).

Comment: The shape of the matrix is (2351, 36092), but, I am still having this issue. The highest scores are assigned to the stop words.